# Bootstrap panel positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, class, row

I have three divs, and can't seem to position it the way I want, even after hours of researching.
I'm using bootstrap rows and columns.

[I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYdRQ.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujyq5.png)

None of the classes have a set height.

Comment: This is because of the height problem , may you need to work with masonry plugins

Comment: or you need to set this in 2 rows

Comment: Provide code, please... check this out - http://www.bootply.com/tagged/masonry

Comment: add your code. what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to put A and C in the same col-xs-6.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6"> Container A, Container C</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6"> Container B </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to divide screen by two parts (6:6 or 7:5) then nest inside them another elements

```css
.d1 {
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
}
.d2 {
    height: 200px;
    background: lightgreen;
}
.d3 {
    height: 100px;
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 d1"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 d3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 d2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

**HTML Code**

```
<table class="container">
  <tr>
    <td class="right">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="filler"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="left">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  border: 1px solid #080808;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}

.right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.right .top {
  border: 1px solid #080808;
  height: 49%;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.right .bottom {
  border: 1px solid #080808;
  height: 49%;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.filler {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**Fiddle Link**

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhavanaditya/n670ydt8/17/)